# golang: quickly access data of maps within maps

Tags: json, go

So I've got the following bit of JSON and I want to pull out the "$t" value under "token".  Continue for Go code...

```
{
  "@encoding": "iso-8859-1",
  "@version": "1.0",
  "service": {
    "auth": {
      "expiresString": {
        "$t": "2013-06-12T01:15:28Z"
      },
      "token": {
        "$t": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      "expires": {
        "$t": "1370999728"
      },
      "key": {
        "$t": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    }
}
```

I have the following snippet of Go code that unmarshals the json into an interface. Then I work my way down to the "$t" value of "token".  This approach does work, but it's ugly.

**My question: is there a faster way to access that value than by converting each map into an interface?**  I'm very new to Go and am not aware of many of the useful features of interfaces and maps.

```
var f interface{}
jerr := json.Unmarshal(body, &f)
m := f.(map[string]interface{})
ser := m["service"].(map[string]interface{})
a := ser["auth"].(map[string]interface{})
tok := a["token"].(map[string]interface{})
token := tok["$t"]
fmt.Fprintf(w, "Token: %v\n", token)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If that's the only value you want, then how about using an anonymous `struct` that defines the path to your data.

```
var m = new(struct{Service struct{Auth struct{Token map[string]string}}})

var err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &m)

fmt.Println(m.Service.Auth.Token["$t"], err)
```

***DEMO:*** http://play.golang.org/p/ZdKTzM5i57

---

Instead of using a `map` for the innermost data, we could use another struct, but we'd need to provide a field tag to alias the name.

```
var m = new(struct{Service struct{Auth struct{Token struct{T string `json:"$t"`}}}})

var err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &m)

fmt.Println(m.Service.Auth.Token.T, err)
```

***DEMO:*** http://play.golang.org/p/NQTpaUvanx

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for including both versions.

Answer (score 7):

OR you can use `objects.Map` from our stew package, it gives you dot accessors for maps:

```
objects.Map(data).Get("service.auth.token")
```

see http://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/stew/objects

Comment: Your project has no documentation anywhere, it's licence is not even displayed on the pkg website